# Как вывести данные без перезагрузки страниц при добавлении нового записи в базу данных?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

У меня есть таблица и все записи отображается на странице.  Спустя какое-то время в неге автоматический добавляется запись. И его надо вывести на страницу без перезагрузки страниц. Как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Вы же прямо в тэгах к вопросу написали ответ :)

AJAX

ну а если вопрос в том, как узнать, что на сервере в базе что-то изменилось - то :

- либо ajax-ом дергаем сервер раз в Х секунд
- либо long polling
- либо web sockets

Comment: Я почти все сделал. Вот не могу вывести на страницу если в базе что-то изменилось.

Comment: @ttt вам сказали `либо ajax-ом дергаем сервер раз в Х секунд` - то есть проверяем изменения, если изменилось выводим на странице, иначе - нет.